# What is the main activity called for mobile Chrome on Android?

Tags: android

What is the main activity called for mobile Chrome on Android?

Is it `Activity`? `Main`?

Comment: Why do you need it? What happens if it is not installed?

Comment: I need it for test automation

Comment: Exactly, if you're not an android developer and just needing it for mobile browser test automation, it's not so trivial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to start chrome with adb as the following:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

Answer (score 3):

termux app on android can start chome app with:

```
am start --user 0 -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

It is even possible to open an url:

```
am start --user 0 -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main http://www.google.com
```